# Substring from a header shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, grep

I need help, I have the next line from a tcpdump header:

```
11:46:24.851239 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 11289, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 229)
```

I need specify a value of header (example: proto) and the result must be:

```
proto UDP (17)
```

I'm trying use that shell script program:

```
var=flags
echo '11:46:24.851239 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 11289, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 229)' | grep -oP "\b$var+"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
echo '11:46:24.851239 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 11289, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 229)' | grep -o 'proto [^,]\+'
```

Using variable:

```
$ x="proto"
$ echo '11:46:24.85123........., proto UDP (17), length 229)' | grep -o "${x} [^,]\+"
proto UDP (17)
```